# Is there a built in function to determine the newest ClickOnce version that was published?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clickonce

I am deploying a WinForms application with ClickOnce.
The app has 40 users.
Sometimes users access the app via the app that was installed on their PC and **not** from the shortcut icon on their desktop. The shortcut is routing them to the local network folder to download the latest software updates.

I am using the `System.Version` class to determine the version number of the application that the user runs on his PC:

```
Dim VersionBeoforeString As Version = Nothing
'Version Number
VersionBeoforeString = Main_Menu.CurrentVersion
```

**i was wondering if there is a built in function that i can use to determine if the version that the client is running on his PC is the newest version?** Or do I need to develop it myself.

Comment: `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion` found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5e56784-550e-48d6-8f19-ea9068b310db/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-an-already-installed-clickonce-application-using-cnet-code?forum=winformssetup)

Comment: intersting, i will check it tommorow. thank you.